# is there a way to able to read text from such images using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, ocr

https://imgur.com/a/zCmwUEf.jpg

this is the image from whom i am trying to extract text but unable to do so.

```
import contours
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\tan\tesseract\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# Opening the image & storing it in an image object
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/tan/Desktop/my tppc bots/training challange - Copy/sample4.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (18, 18))
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations=1)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
im2 = img.copy()
file = open("recognized.txt", "w+")
file.write("")
file.close()
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    file = open("recognized.txt", "a")
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped)
    file.write(text)
    file.write("\n")
```

this is my script
when i run it, it execute fine but when i open the text file it doesnt show any texts there just empty.

am i doing something wrong?

if someone can help me that be great
thanks!

Comment: did you try to ```print(text)``` before writting in the txt file?

Answer (score 1):

I have found **easyocr** lib promising here.

Import the libs

```
import numpy as np
import easyocr
import cv2
```

read the image file

```
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'],gpu = False) # load once only in memory.
image_file_name='capImage.png' # this is the screen snap of your image
image = cv2.imread(image_file_name)
```

get the text from image

```
image_text=(reader.readtext(image,detail=0)[0]) # output came as D F7BE1
print(image_text.replace(" ","")) # removed the space and output is : DF7BE1
```

clean up options for image :

```
image = cv2.imread(image_file_name)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, sharpen_kernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
height = 100
dim = (800, 800)
resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

now utilize the images.

```
image_text=(reader.readtext(thresh,detail=0)[0])
print(image_text.replace(" ",""))

image_text=(reader.readtext(sharpen,detail=0)[0])
print(image_text.replace(" ",""))
```

**output:**
[image]

Comment: hi simple after writing your solution its shows this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tan\Desktop\my bots\functions.py", line 11, in <module>
    image_text=(reader.readtext(image,detail=0)[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: seems like it did not pick the text from the image. was it the same image or something else?

Comment: it was with same image

Comment: also its giving me this error as well image_text=(reader.readtext(img,detail=0)[0])
NameError: name 'reader' is not defined

Comment: add your code;there is something missing.also if you received any error.

Comment: thanks.sorry, i missed that. Added reader line. pls try now.

Comment: now it shows this Using CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.
7A8c2272

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: so you have machine with gpu. great!  all looks okay.did you got the text now?

Comment: thanks it works but with some other image not this one, i tried with different image it worked with that so guess its not 100% of getting result every time?

Comment: Sometimes text is blur or text is not sharp, in those scenarios needs to transform the image so the text is much visible. can I see the image where it did not work? Maybe I can suggest something about it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/JKZyD4u  as you can see in this image when i used the above script it shows this text DT7BEI2C

Comment: I need to see cap3.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zCmwUEf this is the one as it is saved in the path with named as cap3

Comment: how do you sharp image or avoid blury image

Comment: I believe behind the scene os does matter. I ran my program on mac and it gave me the right result. interesting! I will add some options you can try before feeding the image to reader.readtext.

Comment: added, try pls. also attached my result for your reference.

Comment: image_text=(reader.readtext(sharpen,detail=0)[0])
print(image_text.replace(" ",""))   with this i am getting all DF7BE1"< but getting this as an extra "<

Comment: I think this is the best it can do, so the next would be build a model and train it.